# ¿Por qué me da ERROR 1064 (42000) este trigger en mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER AAVSUMATARJETAS AFTER INSERT ON AAVTARJETAS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE AAVCODIGOSFABRICANTES
        SET numtarjetas = numtarjetas + 1
    WHERE AAVCODIGOSFABRICANTES.codfabricante = NEW.fabricante
END |
```

---

El atributo **fabricante** es una parte de una PRIMARY KEY COMPUESTA, y cuando intento crear el trigger me sale el error 1064 (42000) y no me deja ejecutarlo.

¿Alguien sabría decirme porque no funciona?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Alberto. Bienvenido al Sitio. Y el texto del error? No podemos adivinar el texto con sólo el número de error. En la próxima, por favor lo incluyes. Al parecer se trata de un error de sintaxis. Por lo tanto, la respuesta a la pregunta es: **Porque tienes un error de sintaxis**

Comment: Agregue un punto y coma (`;`) al final de la sentencia `UPDATE`: `... NEW.fabricante;`.